# How to set a custom ClaimsPrincipal in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I created a custom principal class

```
public class FacebookPrincipal : ClaimsPrincipal
{
    public JObject Data { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to use it. When the user logs in, I tried to set

```
var fbP = new FacebookPrincipal { Data = user.Data };

Thread.CurrentPrincipal = fbP;
AuthenticationManager.User = fbP;
HttpContext.User = fbP;
```

It works right after I set it, but when I go ho `home/index` the value is lost

```
var user = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User;
var bbbb = this.User;
var cccc = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
```

All the above methods return a Principal of type `ClaimsPrincipal` and casting to `FacebookPrincipal` returns null.

How do I set a custom principal?

Comment: What does the enumeration of the [`Claims`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.claims(v=vs.110).aspx) property return?

Comment: `[0] = {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: #########}` - `[1] = {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: ####}` - `[2] = {http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider: ASP.NET Identity}`

Comment: Here's a solution I posted on a similar question:
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/25731422/264672](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25731422/264672)

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET Identity uses default `ClaimsIdentityFactory` to create before assigning `ClaimsIdentity` to User and Thread. You should create your own `ClaimsIdentityFactory` where you can add or manage additional information.

```
UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager 
          = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());
userManager.ClaimsIdentityFactory 
          = new MyClaimsIdentityFactory<IdentityUser>();
```

And the following code to create your implementation for ClaimsIdentity or its subclass.

```
public class MyClaimsIdentityFactory<IUser> : ClaimsIdentityFactory<IUser> where IUser : IdentityUser
{
    public MyClaimsIdentityFactory(): base()
    {

    }
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity> CreateAsync(UserManager<IUser> manager, IUser user, string authenticationType)
    {
        // Override Creation of ClaimsIdentity and return it.
    }
}
```

- Make sure you absolutely need to subclass ClaimsIdentity. You can add additional info as Claims.
- You shall use `base.CreateAsync` and merge the `Claims` to your created `ClaimsIdentity`.

Comment: There is no need for custom ClaimsIdentityFactory, additional claims can be added by implementing IUserClaimStore interface for your user store.

Answer (score 1):

•Make sure you absolutely need to subclass ClaimsIdentity. You can add additional info as Claims.

You should be careful about adding additional claims for supplementary information as a side effect can be a change to how the authorization policy will make decisions.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @marisks, you can use `IUserClaimsStore` to store claims issued from third-party for your user. only if the custom claims access is the problem.

Moreover, to persist the identity between two requests, use following code.

```
// One can create one's own Identity here.
var identity = await 
    UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, 
                                    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

// Or add custom claims. Claims Stored in IUserClaimStore 
// are already populated by above creation.
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ProfileDATA", "VALUE"));

AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() 
                                   { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
```