# How can I get the specific fields of the currently logged-in user in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC5 app that uses Individual Authentication, and of course ASP.NET Identity. The point is that I had extended I have a model that inherits from ApplicationUser, it is simply defined like this:

```
public class NormalUser : ApplicationUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

So, the point is that, first of all I want to check whether there is a logged-in user, and if there is, I want to get his/her FirstName, LastName and Email fields. How can I achieve it?

I think I need to use something like this to check whether there is a logged-in user:

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    ...
}
```

But, how can I get those specific fields' values for the current user?

Comment: can you not use or implement some code that uses `PrincipalContext`

Comment: @DJKRAZE No idea about it.

Comment: it's very simple to use and you can get at the users name via athe samAccount there are plenty of examples actually.. when the user launches the page or site you can easily get at that information

Comment: @ett Are you using the claims-based ASP.NET Identity 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in Identity, if you need additional user information, you just pull the user from the database, since this is all stored on the actual user object now.

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
}
```

If `GetUserId` isn't on `User.Identity`, add the following to your usings:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

Comment: To pull the data from the DB every time you need the user's first & last name seems very inefficient to me.

Comment: This works all fine for getting the Email, but not for getting the FirstName and LastName fields. Using the above I can only get the standard ApplicationUser fields, not the fields that I added later.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the subclass. Well, when you instantiate `UserManager`, you have to specify the user class that is going to be utilized. You're probably just using the default which is `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`, which is only going to return `ApplicationUser` instances that don't have `FirstName` and `LastName` properties. So, you can either instantiate `UserManager<NormalUser>` or just use your context directly via `context.Users.OfType<NormalUser>.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId())`

Comment: Please note that those things are defined in my AccountContoller, but now I'm working in my HomeController. When I do something like `ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext(); var user = db.Users.OfType<NormalUser>.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId())`, I get an error message at OfType is a method, which is not valid in the given context. And if I use `UserManager<NormalUser>(User.Identity.GetUserId())`, I get an error message UserManager<NormalUser> is a type but is used like a variable.

Comment: On the first point, that was my fault. I neglected the parenthesis after, i.e `OfType<NormalUser>()`. On the second point, you can't use `UserManager<NormalUser>` directly, you need to define a variable of that type, i.e. `var userManager = new UserManager<NormalUser>(new UserStore<NormalUser>());`

Comment: Well, now it says that the method Find does not exists. And about the second part, when I instantiate a new UserManager as you have done, then how can I get the fields that I want?

Comment: Any idea for those problems?

Answer (score 10):

In MVC5 the user data is stored by default in the session and upon request the data is parsed into a `ClaimsPrincipal` which contains the username (or id) and the claims.

This is the way I chose to implement it, it might not be the simplest solution but it definitely makes it easy to use.

**Example of usage:**

In controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.ReverseDisplayName = this.User.LastName + ", " + this.User.FirstName;
}
```

In view or _Layout:

```
@if(User.IsAuthenticated)
{
     <span>@User.DisplayName</span>
}
```

**1. Replace ClaimsIdentityFactory**

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Domain.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

public class AppClaimsIdentityFactory : IClaimsIdentityFactory<User, int>
{
    internal const string IdentityProviderClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider";

    internal const string DefaultIdentityProviderClaimValue = "My Identity Provider";

    /// <summary>
    ///     Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public AppClaimsIdentityFactory()
    {
        RoleClaimType = ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType;
        UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
        UserNameClaimType = ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType;
        SecurityStampClaimType = Constants.DefaultSecurityStampClaimType;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Claim type used for role claims
    /// </summary>
    public string RoleClaimType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Claim type used for the user name
    /// </summary>
    public string UserNameClaimType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Claim type used for the user id
    /// </summary>
    public string UserIdClaimType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Claim type used for the user security stamp
    /// </summary>
    public string SecurityStampClaimType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Create a ClaimsIdentity from a user
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="manager"></param>
    /// <param name="user"></param>
    /// <param name="authenticationType"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateAsync(UserManager<User, int> manager, User user, string authenticationType)
    {
        if (manager == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("manager");
        }
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        }
        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(authenticationType, UserNameClaimType, RoleClaimType);
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(UserIdClaimType, user.Id.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String));
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(UserNameClaimType, user.UserName, ClaimValueTypes.String));
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(IdentityProviderClaimType, DefaultIdentityProviderClaimValue, ClaimValueTypes.String));

        id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.EmailAddress));
        if (user.ContactInfo.FirstName != null && user.ContactInfo.LastName != null)
        {
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.ContactInfo.FirstName));
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.ContactInfo.LastName));
        }

        if (manager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
        {
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(SecurityStampClaimType,
                await manager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user.Id)));
        }
        if (manager.SupportsUserRole)
        {
            user.Roles.ToList().ForEach(r =>
                id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, r.Id.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String)));
        }
        if (manager.SupportsUserClaim)
        {
            id.AddClaims(await manager.GetClaimsAsync(user.Id));
        }
        return id;
    }
```

**2. Change the `UserManager` to use it**

```
public static UserManager<User,int> Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<AppUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
{
    var manager = new UserManager<User,int>(new UserStore<User,int>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
    {
        ClaimsIdentityFactory = new AppClaimsIdentityFactory()
    };

    // more initialization here

    return manager;
}
```

**3. Create a new custom `Principal`**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;

public class UserPrincipal : ClaimsPrincipal
{
    public UserPrincipal(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        : base(principal.Identities)
    {
    }

    public int UserId
    {
        get { return FindFirstValue<int>(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier); }
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return FindFirstValue<string>(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType); }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get { return FindFirstValue<string>(ClaimTypes.Email); }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return FindFirstValue<string>(ClaimTypes.GivenName); }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return FindFirstValue<string>(ClaimTypes.Surname); }
    }

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            var name = string.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstName, this.LastName).Trim();
            return name.Length > 0 ? name : this.UserName;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> Roles
    {
        get { return FindValues<int>(ClaimTypes.Role); }
    }

    private T FindFirstValue<T>(string type)
    {
        return Claims
            .Where(p => p.Type == type)
            .Select(p => (T)Convert.ChangeType(p.Value, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> FindValues<T>(string type)
    {
        return Claims
            .Where(p => p.Type == type)
            .Select(p => (T)Convert.ChangeType(p.Value, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

**4. Create an `AuthenticationFilter` to use it**

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Filters;


public class AppAuthenticationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
    {
        //This method is responsible for setting and modifying the principle for the current request though the filterContext .
        //Here you can modify the principle or applying some authentication logic.  
        var principal = filterContext.Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;
        if (principal != null && !(principal is UserPrincipal))
        {
            filterContext.Principal = new UserPrincipal(principal);
        }
    }

    public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
    {
        //This method is responsible for validating the current principal and permitting the execution of the current action/request.
        //Here you should validate if the current principle is valid / permitted to invoke the current action. (However I would place this logic to an authorization filter)
        //filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("CustomErrorPage",null);
    }
}
```

**5. Register the auth filter to load globally in the `FilterConfig`**

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute()); 
    filters.Add(new AppAuthenticationFilterAttribute());
}
```

By now the `Principal` is persisted and all we have left to do is expose it in the Controller and View.

**6. Create a controller base class**

```
public abstract class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    public new UserPrincipal User
    {
        get { return HttpContext.User as UserPrincipal; }
    }
}
```

**7. Create a `WebViewPage` base class and modify the `web.config` to use it**

```
public abstract class BaseViewPage : WebViewPage
{
    public virtual new UserPrincipal User
    {
        get { return base.User as UserPrincipal; }
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticated
    {
        get { return base.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; }
    }
}

public abstract class BaseViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public virtual new UserPrincipal User
    {
        get { return base.User as UserPrincipal; }
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticated
    {
        get { return base.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; }
    }
}
```

And the `web.config` inside the `Views` folder:

```
<pages pageBaseType="MyApp.Web.Views.BaseViewPage">
```

**Important!**

Do not store too much data on the `Principal` since this data is passed back and forth on each request.

Comment: (not your fault) This is nuts what was MS thinking? Goodness.