# Custom ClaimsPrincipal or ClaimsIdentity (where to graft it?)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

Where can I extend ASP.NET current (5.0) Identity functionality to easily resolve the integer user ID and security rights associated with a claim?

This should be available within all of my web application browser service access points (everywhere a cookie or JWT is provided), including SignalR hub, MVC controller, and WebAPI controller. It should work with OWIN Authentication.

---

Here are the three most-related solutions I've seen, and why they don't work:

Set `HttpContext.Current.User` in every call via global.asax `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest`. I've seen older (MVC 4) functionality that obsoletes this. I know global.asax is generally not the way to go today. I'm also using OWIN; this may not even work at all.

Override `ClaimsPrincipal ClaimsAuthenticationManager.Authenticate()` with the configuration `<system.identityModel><identityConfiguration><claimsAuthenticationManager type = "CustomClaimsAuthenticatonManager" />` However, `ClaimsAuthenticationManager` is from `System.Identity`, which isn't even in the references of my ASP.NET 5.0 project with `ClaimsAuthentication` active. Instead I have references to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core` stuff in my project from current NuGet packages. It seems this approach is not for ASP.NET apps, or at least not current ones?

Set `UserManager.ClaimsIdentityFactory` to a custom `ClaimsIdentityFactory`, with overridden `CreateAsync`. This looks like this might work, but I don't see any way to graft that onto the current ASP.NET default behavior. See here: [How to set a custom ClaimsPrincipal in MVC 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763807/how-to-set-a-custom-claimsprincipal-in-mvc-5)

Comment: Do you want to use with your own tables or Identity's auto generated tables?

Comment: I would prefer to be using my own tables. Right now I'm using neither, technically, as neither the claims authentication nor authorization processes are touching the Identity UserStore. Account information is of course being stored in my database.

Comment: I am trying to get the name of the Group that the group SID belongs to.  I am using windows authentication to pull in the user.  How can I convert the GroupSID to the name of the groups that the user belongs to?

Comment: Any updates of this one?  I've got customisations going on for services, but am struggling to see where custom User can be accessed on the controller.  Ideally I want something like a IUserContext to pass around from controllers.  I could add claims to which could be accessed from a singleton of IUserContext that could be injected to a controller.

Comment: Please check this SO answer for a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337045/where-to-set-custom-claimsprincipal-for-all-httprequests